# How do I prevent myself from leaning too close to the monitor?

Tags: ergonomics

Sometimes I get too excited about something I'm doing with my computer and I tend to lean closer and closer to the monitor, though it becomes harder to read and my neck starts hurting. Usually I snap out of it when my neck is hurting enough to leech off all my attention that was previously focused on that overwhelming activity.

I would like to find a way to remember not to sit or lean too closely to the monitor before I hurt my eyes or neck.

Comment: This isn't a productivity question, but may be appropriate on Workplace.SE

Comment: Although the question may not look like it on first glance, it's a poll, and it's attracted answers that don't explain why and how or that are backed by facts and references. This isn't what our site is about. Instead, polling for ideas on this topic would be great for [chat] as the topic is somewhat workplace-related. Good luck! :)

Comment: It seems that the lowest quality answers were all part of the migration from another SE site, and they were removed when this was closed. The answers that are visible now are actually not that bad, so if we can [edit] this so it's not a poll, I could see it being possibly reopened. Hope this helps!

Comment: Move your monitor closer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Educate yourself to always stay with the body leaning on the backrest of the chair, it also helps a lot the spinal cord too, because most of that weight will be taken by the chair, not your bones.
  For getting used to always stay on the backrest, you can use a sticky note which you will place in a different position on the margin of the monitor (and change it's color) every day. When you will get close to the monitor, you will see it, and it will remember you about that.
- Feeling the need to get close to the monitor could be a symptom that you eye muscles are tired - try to take short but often breaks away from the computer, so you can give them a rest. If you get close, you will get you eyes even more tired.
- Check to see that you have an ergonomic position, and the 'default' distance is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to zoom in on your content. Many Programs do support this.

All Browsers and IDEs I worked with on Windows supported it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Wheel</kbd>. Your Program may support this, too.

By this solution you are "leaning close" only mentally and not physically.

Answer (score 0):

Sit on a chair without a backrest.  Then you cannot do this without falling down.

I can personally recommend one of these:

[image: Variér Move]

http://www.varierfurniture.com/Collections/Work/Move/